# MySQL: How to limit the results to the last 5 rows

Tags: php, mysql

this show last 10 new results and all ok

```
$query = "SELECT s.name AS song,
                 SUM(v.hit_shit) AS hit,
                 COUNT(v.hit_shit) - SUM(v.hit_shit) AS shit,
                 MAX(date_voted) AS last_vote
            FROM songs AS s
           INNER JOIN votes AS v ON v.song_id = s.id
           WHERE v.date_voted >= CURDATE()
           GROUP BY s.id
           ORDER BY last_vote DESC
           LIMIT 10";
$song = mysql_query($query);
```

but this show all , but i need only 5 :(

```
$query = "SELECT s.name AS song,
                 SUM(v.hit_shit) AS hit,
                 COUNT(v.hit_shit) - SUM(v.hit_shit) AS shit
            FROM songs AS s
           INNER JOIN votes AS v ON v.song_id = s.id
           WHERE v.date_voted >= CURDATE()
             AND v.date_voted < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
           GROUP BY s.id
           ORDER BY hit DESC, shit ASC, song ASC";
$song = mysql_query($query);
```

p.s. sorry 4 my bad eng

Comment: Change `LIMIT 10` to `LIMIT 5`

Comment: You didn't you notice `LIMIT 10` in your query? First thing I would have tried was changing that from 10 to 5.

Comment: why is there so much shit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add parameter "LIMIT" at the end of your query.

```
$query = "SELECT s.name AS song,
                 SUM(v.hit_shit) AS hit,
                 COUNT(v.hit_shit) - SUM(v.hit_shit) AS shit
            FROM songs AS s
           INNER JOIN votes AS v ON v.song_id = s.id
           WHERE v.date_voted >= CURDATE()
             AND v.date_voted < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
           GROUP BY s.id
           ORDER BY hit DESC, shit ASC, song ASC
           LIMIT 5";

$song = mysql_query($query);
```

Edit: Modified Code Formatting.

Comment: @user2912266 Are the tables songs and votes large? read 100000 records or more?

Answer (score 1):

Add Limit 5 to the end of your query.

```
$query = "SELECT s.name AS song,
                 SUM(v.hit_shit) AS hit,
                 COUNT(v.hit_shit) - SUM(v.hit_shit) AS shit,
                 MAX(date_voted) AS last_vote
            FROM songs AS s
           INNER JOIN votes AS v ON v.song_id = s.id
           WHERE v.date_voted >= CURDATE()
           GROUP BY s.id
           ORDER BY last_vote DESC
           LIMIT 5";

$song = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: about first code i know but second? :(

Comment: That is how you limit the amount of returned queries. If you only want 5 results, Limit the first 5 results.